# xCode unity-iphone requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I've been trying for days to submit a Unity app to the App Market but can't get around an error saying something about a provisioning profile. I'm logged in with xCode to my app developer account and just want to deploy it. code signing is set to automatic and my developer team is set.

[image: xCode error]

Yet somehow xCode keeps complaining about some profile which I just cannot find. Someone else with this problem before? Please tell me the correct configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the solution lies NOT in the build settings but in a different more "generale" panel. here you can either upload provisioning files made online through developer.apple.com or either check automatic provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Release instead of Debug

It works for me

Select Unity-Iphone -> Signing and Capabilities, choose Release (sometimes is selected Debug)  and check the signing with your team.